# Get exact rotation angle from matrix3d

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have some element

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

with rotation transform style

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-1100deg);
```

Is there a way to get exact (-1100) rotation angle from computed styles?

`window.getComputedStyle` returns matrix3d.

```
var element = document.getElementById('element'),
    cs = getComputedStyle(element),
    matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(cs['-webkit-transform']);
```

But how to retrieve rotation angle out of this matrix?

I need computed styles because Im trying to get angle during transition of element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy way to do it, but with the help of [this article](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) I managed to get the value (kind of).

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('element');
var myTransform = window.getComputedStyle(myElement,null)
var myTransform = myTransform.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform");
var myTransform = myTransform.split(' ');
var myX = myTransform[6].split(",")[0];
var angle = Math.round(Math.asin(myX) * (180/Math.PI));
console.log(angle);
```

It returns -20, which is -360 * 3 = -1080 + the added 20 degree rotation. -20. Some guy in the comments noticed that it doesn't work when the angle is above 180deg and offered **[a solution](http://codepen.io/jjeaton/pen/bzolH)**, but it only works up to 360deg.

I think it would be way much easier if you use javascript to dynamically control the transformation of your elements, since there is no easier way to get the `getComputedStyle` value of your rotation.

Comment: As I've understand its impossible to get exact angle, because matrices for 360deg and 720deg are identical http://jsfiddle.net/WsN4W/. But I workaround it with help of solution u suggested for 360deg. Thank you.