# I have a problem using css3 animation direction

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Hello fellow developers,

I am trying to build a rotation over Z axis by using a CSS3 animation

```
HTML
///

<div>
<div id="rotZ" class = "square">ROTATE</div>
</div>

CSS
///
div {
    perspective: 500px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
    animation: rotateAnimation 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
    from {transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
}


JS
///
var direction = 'normal';

var d = document.getElementById('rotZ');

d.addEventListener('click', changeDir);

function changeDir() {
    direction = direction == 'normal' ? 'reverse' : 'normal';
    
    d.style.animationDirection = direction;
}
```

like in this codepen https://codepen.io/pdelia/pen/QWpZvOr

What I want is to reverse the animation back and forth when clicking on div.

The code works, but the rotationZ value of the div is changing so I can't achieve what I need.

I tried to get the rotateZ value in degrees (so I could change the keyframes accordingly) by using getComputedStyle() but what it returns is a matrix3d object and whatever I tried to convert to degrees failed.
Relevant posts in stackoverflow like [Get 3D CSS rotation value from matrix3d() with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450835/get-3d-css-rotation-value-from-matrix3d-with-javascript) and [Get exact rotation angle from matrix3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013335/get-exact-rotation-angle-from-matrix3d/24014936) do not return a valid value.

Is there anything I can do to change rotation direction at that particular Z value so the animation looks smooth?

Comment: Can you post your CSS as well please

Comment: It's in the codepen I included but I am adding here too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth CSS Transition Animation Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003657/smooth-css-transition-animation-rotation)

Comment: The solution suggested in the link works by adding an outer div running the opposite direction at double speed so the inner div looks like changing direction, but in my occasion can't work because I need the inner spin to stop, do some things in code according the time elapsed before pressing the stop button and then change direction and then start running again, so I believe the only valid approach is to know the exact degree where it stopped.